# Binary Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'Int8' and 'Int'

Tags: swift, swift3

since i converted the code to Swift 3 i get this error:

```
Binary Operator '==' can not be applied to operands of type 'Int8' and 'Int'
```

In Swift 2 it worked with this:

```
    var flags : UInt8
    var count : Int = 1
    var zw = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: 2)

    let countTotal = data.count / MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size

    var bytes = [UInt8](repeating: 0, count: countTotal)

    data.copyBytes(to: &bytes, count: countTotal*MemoryLayout<UInt8>.size)

    flags = bytes[0]
    if([0x01 & flags] == [0 & 0x01]) // **<--ERROR**
    {
        zw[0] = bytes[count]
        zw[1] = bytes[count + 1
        let bpsys = UnsafePointer(zw).withMemoryRebound(to: UInt16.self, capacity: 1)
        {
            $0.pointee
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the wrong bracket (`[` instead of `(`) to begin with. But it looks like Swift 3 changed the type inference system in a subtle way that broke your program. Try this:

```
if (0x01 & flags) == (0 & 0x01) {

}
```

Last question is why? `0 & 0x01` always return 0. You may as well write:

```
if 0x01 & flag == 0 {

}
```

Comment: @Florian, if the answer works and is the *actual* issue - it appears to be - please accept it. That helps everyone who encounters this. Thanks.